# Rails Active Admin Coffescript not compiling in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript, activeadmin

Rails 3.2 I have a coffee script file which works fine in development. When I push to prod I get this error when I go to the login page:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (utils.js.coffee isn't precompiled):
    9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag style.path, style.options.dup %>
    10:   <% end %>
    11:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.each do |path| %>
    12:     <%= javascript_include_tag path %>
    13:   <% end %>
    14: 
    15:   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

My active_admin.js and the utils.js.coffee file mentioned are in `./app/assets/javascripts`. I am not even sure where to begin with debugging this other than making sure `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` was run in prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` should place your assets in `public/assets/` directory.

Change `config.serve_static_assets` to `true` in  your `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Then restart your rails server.

**Update:**

Change `config.assets.compile` to `true` in `config/environments/production.rb` to let Sprockets handle the assets in pipeline.  See "[Live Compilation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#live-compilation)".

Comment: @ScottJShea, have you tried `config.assets.compile = true` in production.rb?

Comment: @ScottJShea, Great, you're welcome.  I've added that bit to my answer.